# Parsing a string and pushing integers values into vector of structs c++

Tags: c++, struct

I have this assignment for my cpts class where I need to parse through a string that looks something like this

set(45,0;34,1;12,2)

The struct is

```
struct item
{
    int value;
    int index;
};
```

So in essense if the first item into the vector would be

```
{value = 45 
index = 0}
```

The , in the "set" lineseperates the value and the index, where the ; seperates whole item object. My first attempt at parsing the line is this:

```
int index = 7;
int data = 4;
int a = 0;
item *i;
vector<item> newVect;
for (a = 0; a < fromfile.length(); a++)
{

    i->value = stoi(fromfile.substr(data));
    i->index = stoi(fromfile.substr(index));

    newVect.push_back(*i);


    index += 5;
    data  += 5;

    i++;
}
```

but it crashes when index and data go out of the range of the line and not really sure how to only extract the integers out of the line. Please help! This is the only part of the assignment im stuck on. I've been trying to figure it out in the last 10 hours. Sorry for any format issues, new to posting on coding forums.

My set functions accepts a string& line type

Comment: help yourself or help us help you: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Your are dereferencing uninitialized pointer.

Answer (score 0):

It is crashing because you haven't pointed "i" at anything, and yet you dereference it!

`i->value` and `i->data` are at this point arbitrary locations in memory, and you are likely overwriting something you shouldn't.

Instead of using `item *i;`, use `item i`.   and then instead of using `i->` use `i.`, and instead of using `push(*i)` just use `push(i)`.

The other reason your code is "crashing" is that you're assuming constant size records (+= 5).  Instead, you need to find the next '`,`', '`;`' or '`)`'.

The final reason is you're running a from 0 to the length of the string (in this case 20). But youre"index" and "data" values go up to 7+5*20 and 4+5*20 respectively. This is well beyond the end of the string. (107 and 104 respectively, for a string that is 20 bytes long).

Comment: It still crashes when index hits 32. This is the actual set string im testing it against.set(56,0;22,1;77,2;91,3;34,4;102,5;61,7)

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a number of problems but I'll focus on the crashy ones.

```
item *i;
```

This creates a pointer variable, `i`, with no default value. Use of this variable will result in "undefined behavior" upto and including crashing.

```
i->value = stoi(fromfile.substr(data));
i->index = stoi(fromfile.substr(index));
```

you still haven't assigned a value to `i` so it's pointing to some random place in memory. This is bad and will cause undefined behavior upto and including crashing.

```
newVect.push_back(*i);
```

You are explicitly dereferencing unintialized `i` to copy its values into a new item at the back of `newVect`. `i` is uninitialized, though, so ... undefined behavior.

```
i++;
```

Question: What is uninitialized + 1?
Answer: uninitialized.

I'm not going to help you solve your pointer problems, because it seems unnecessary since you are copying `*i`:

```
item i; // no pointer, now we have an i to work with.

for ( ... ) {
    i.value = ...;
    i.index = ...;
    newVect.push_back(i);
    // don't do i++
}
```

This solves your problems but is slightly wasteful because we have to copy everything. If you have access to C++11 you can do the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Item {
    Item (int value_, int index_) : value(value_), index(index_) {}
    int value;
    int index;
};

int main()
{
    int index = 7;
    int data = 4;
    std::vector<Item> newVect;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        newVect.emplace_back(index, data);
        index += 5;
        data  += 5;
    }    

    for (size_t i = 0; i < newVect.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << "#" << i << ": " << newVect[i].value
            << ", " << newVect[i].index << "\n";
    }
}
```

See http://ideone.com/6NoMba